# Pyttsx3 not working, process finished with exit code 0

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyttsx3

I am making an Artificial Intelligence (AI) assistant and I wrote this to make it speak:

```
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voices', voices[0].id)


def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    print(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()
```

it does not speak and shows:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

how to fix it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use the function. Use this code:

```
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voices', voices[0].id)


def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    print(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()


# what you are missing
# use your function to say something
speak('Hello')
```

Hopefully, it works!